# Two-factor ANOVA: What should be done when each cell has only one observation?

Tags: anova, two-way

I have a data set, described as the measurement of insecticide found through four different extraction methods, A, B, C, and D.  A measurement for each extraction method is made under the conditions when the flower is: Fresh, 1-year untreated, and 1-year treated.  The data set looks like:

```
               A  B  C  D
Fresh:         1  2  3  2
1yr untreated: 2  3  1  3
1yr treated:   5  3  2  4
```

I am asked to propose a model for the data and estimate its parameters.  By the description of the data, it sounds like it just has to be a two-factor ANOVA.  Both the extraction method and the "freshness" seem like independent and relevant variables controlling the outcome.  Moreover, I would think it's fair to suspect interaction effects.  So this sounds like my proposed model ...

Except, each cell has only one observation.  My textbook says that we cannot conduct a hypothesis test without at least two observations per cell.  So now it sounds like perhaps I can't use this model.

On the other hand, I'm not asked to actually conduct a hypothesis test, only estimate parameters.  So for instance, can I still estimate the value of $\mu \approx \hat{\mu} = X...$, which is to say average over the $i,j,k$ coordinates (here, $k=1$ always)?  And likewise for the formulae to estimate the "row-" and "column-" and "interaction-effects"?